# Autofit last row to occupy the entire column using Grid Template

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I have seven div inside a container and 7th div need to occupy the entire column space

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>  
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
  <div class="item7">7</div>
</div>
```

Expected

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the column to span 3

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item7 {
    grid-column: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>  
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
  <div class="item7">7</div>
</div>
```